# MySQL join - data not in second table

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables, t1 containing events, t2 containing "attended" events, and t3 containing some invited user ids (linked to system user ids). More than one user can attend and event.

When a new event is created it's inserted into t1. Every time a user confirms attending an event a row is inserted in t2, otherwise the t2 table is empty.

The query bellow pulls all the events an user is attending.

```
SELECT * FROM events t1
INNER JOIN attending_events t2 ON t1.id_ev = t2.id_ev
INNER JOIN attending_users t3 ON t2.id_user = t3.id_user AND t3.id_system_user=17
WHERE t1.id_comp = 42
```

Please help, I need a query to do the exact opposite, find the events the user is not attending.

Comment: Should events with `id_comp <> 42` be returned?

Comment: @Quassnoi : No, only events from id_bcomp=42 should be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  e.*
FROM    events e
WHERE   e.id_ev NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  id_ev
        FROM    attending_events ae
        JOIN    attending_users au
        ON      au.id_user = ae.id_user
        WHERE   au.system_user_id = 17
        )
        AND id_comp = 42
```

or:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    events e
LEFT JOIN
(
        attending_events ae
JOIN    attending_users au
ON      au.id_user = ae.id_user
)
ON      ae.id_ev = e.id_ev
        AND au.system_user_id = 17
WHERE   e.id_comp = 42
        AND ae.id_ev IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you! So far this is the only way it works and I will use it if I can't find a better solution (without using 2 SELECT statements).

Comment: @noru: what's bad in two `SELECT` statements?

Comment: My boss hating them and always making me look for another way :|

Comment: @noru: use the Mithrandir's solution then, it's almost the same performance-wise (in `MySQL`).

Comment: I commented on his solution, it doesn't (seem to) work. If there is anything I have to change, I don't see it right now.

Comment: Thank you again, it worked like a charm ! On this simple case example, with 10 events and 10 users I see the speed is pretty much the same.

Comment: @noru: in `MySQL`, they are using almost the same plan: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from attending_events where id_ev not in 
(SELECT id_ev FROM events t1
INNER JOIN attending_events t2 ON t1.id_ev = t2.id_ev
INNER JOIN attending_users t3 ON t2.id_user = t3.id_user AND t3.id_system_user=17
WHERE t1.id_comp = 42)
```

first thing came to my mind. Definitely should be optimized.